# How can I extract full android project from apk file?

Tags: android

I have pretty much messed up with my android project in the process of adding ads and have already wasted a lot of time on fixing things. However I have the working app installed on my phone. How can I extract it into full android project so that I need not to spent more on it.

Comment: if you created the mess, you should fix the mess. dont be that guy

Comment: here is it . Got no reliable ans

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47202372/how-to-solve-connection-to-the-internet-denied-error-in-android-studio-3-0

Comment: Start using a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control system and you'll be fine next time